# How can I Activating AnyLogic using USB dongle in Ubuntu OS?

Tags: anylogic

I downloaded the last Anylogic for Unbutu but I can not see AnyLogic Activation Wizard in the help.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you need to request a permanent key from the registration wizard. It does not support the USB